How can I prove $(\star)$? - I nice property of $_2F_1\left(\frac{5}{6},1;\frac{11}{6};-t^6 \right)$
Conjecture (Goal)
Prove or disprove the following:
$$_2F_1\left(\frac{5}{6},1;\frac{11}{6};-t^6 \right) = \frac{5}{t^5}\left(\frac{\pi}{3}- \int_{t}^{\infty}  \frac{x^4}{1+x^6} dx \right) \label{conj} \tag{$*$}$$
for all $t \in (0, \infty)$, where $_2F_1(a,b;c;z)$ is the hypergeometric function. I think I have just discovered this today.
Question
The only thing I need to prove $\eqref{conj}$ is that
$$ \int_{0}^{t^3} \frac{\sqrt[3]{x^2}}{1+x^2} dx =\frac{3}{5}t^{5} \left(  {}_{2}F_{1}\left(\frac{5}{6},1;\frac{11}{6};-t^6 \right) \right) \label{wfa} \tag{$\star$}$$
The equation in $\eqref{wfa}$ was given by Wolfram Alpha. But is this really true?
Motivation
I saw this video from the Bright Side of Mathematics YouTube channel and he proved that
$$ \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^4}{1+x^6} dx = \frac{2\pi}{3}$$
Then I was wondering if there was a number $a \in (0, \infty)$ such that
$$ \int_{a}^{\infty} \frac{x^4}{1+x^6} = \frac{1}{3} \label{I} \tag{I}$$
So, I started to prove $\eqref{I}$ to find an exact value of $a$ for which $\eqref{I}$ is true, but I gave up (not the main point of this post). However, I got an "amazing" idea trying to prove the general result given by $\eqref{conj}$. Finally, I got stuck to prove that the integral on the LHS of $\eqref{wfa}$ is equal to the RHS of $\eqref{wfa}$ and I searched the result using Wolfram Alfa. I don't know how to use the hypergeometric function; it's the first time I see this kind of function.

Why not expand the denominator of the integrand in (*) as a power series and integrate, see if you get the result asked about?

Ok, I'll try. Thanks.

Also, if you want to compute the power series by integrating termwise, it's probably better to verify that $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^4}{1+x^6}dx=\frac{\pi}{3}$ and therefore the integral in (*) can be expressed as $\int_0^t \frac{x^4}{1+x^4}dx$.

@Semiclassical I wrote $\frac{5}{3t^5}$ not $\frac{5}{3t^3}$. However, is it still wrong to leave it as it is (i.e., leaving it as $\frac{5}{3t^5}$)?

Oh, ok! Perfect! And actually, you are right. I figured it out now haha

What definition of $,_2F_1$ can be used in the proof? Additionally, it may help that the hypergeometric function simplifies into the incomplete beta and Lerch transcendent functions.

@ТymaGaidash THIS IS ABSOLUTELY INCREDIBLE!! Love it hhah. With the Lerch transcendental function is soo simple!

An interesting reaction.

The number $a$ you are searching for is extremely close to $3$ (more precisely $2.9994118533653567507$).

@ClaudeLeibovici That's actually amazing! Thanks!

@YoyosTutoring. Using the first iterate of Newton method with $a_0=3$, we have $$a_1=3--\frac{365}{486} \left(-4+2 \tan
^{-1}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)+\tan
^{-1}\left(\frac{48}{55}\right)+2
\sqrt{3} \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{3
\sqrt{3}}{10}\right)\right)=2.99941$$

By definition $$_2F_1\left(\frac{5}{6},1;\frac{11}{6};-t^6 \right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\,\frac{5}{6 n+5}\,t^{6n}$$ The integral does not make much problems
$$I= \int_{t}^{\infty}  \frac{x^4}{1+x^6}\, dx=\frac \pi 3+\frac 16\Big(\tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{3}-2 t\right)-2 \tan
   ^{-1}(t)-\tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{3}+2
   t\right)\Big)+$$
$$\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{3}}\log \left(\frac{1+t\sqrt{3} +t^2 }{1-t\sqrt{3}+t^2} \right)$$
Now
$$\frac{x^4}{1+x^6}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\, x^{4+6n}\quad \implies \quad \int\frac{x^4}{1+x^6}\,dx=C+\sum_{n=0}^\infty  (-1)^n\,\frac{x^{6 n+5}}{6 n+5}$$
Using the bounds and the proper $C$ given above
$$I=\frac \pi 3-\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{t^{6n+5} }{6n+5 }$$
Just finish to prove {$*$}
